# How to do conditional greedy match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, conditional-statements, match, greedy

I want Perl to parse a code text and identify certain stuffs, example code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/(\w+)(\s*<=.*?;)/$1_yes$2/gs;
  print;
}

__DATA__
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
if(!rst_n)begin
        d1 <= 0; //perl_comment_4
        //perl_comment_5
        d2 <= 1  //perl_comment_6
                 + 2;
        end
else if( d3 <= d4 && ( d5 <= 3 ) ) begin
        d6 <= d7 +
                 (d8 <= d9 ? 1 : 0);
        //perl_comment_7
        d10 <= d11 <=
                      d12
                        + d13
                            <= d14 ? 1 : 0;
        end
```

Match target is something that meets all of the following:

(1) It begins with the combination `word\s*<=`. Here `\s*` maybe 0 or more spaces, newlines, tabs.

(2) The aforementioned "combination" should be out of any pair of `(` and `)`.

(3) If multiple "combinations" appear consecutively, then take the first one as the beginning. (Something like "greedy" matching at the left boundary)

(4) it ends with the first `;` after the "combination" mentioned in (1).

There may be `word\s*<=` and `;` in code comments (there may be anything in comments); this makes things more complicated. To make life easier, I already pre-processed the text, scanning for comments and replacing them with stuff like `//perl_comment_6`. (This solution seems rather cumbersome and stupid. Any smarter, more elegant solutions?)

What I wanna do:

For all matched `word\s*<=`, replace `word` with `word_yes`. For the example code, **d1**, **d2**, **d6** and **d10** should be replaced by **d1_yes**, **d2_yes**, **d6_yes** and **d10_yes**, respectively, and all other parts of the text should remain unchanged.

In my current code I use `s/(\w+)(\s*<=.*?;)/$1_yes$2/gs;`, which correctly recognizes **d1**, **d2** and **d10**, but fails to recognize **d6** and mistakenly recognizes **d3**.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance~

Comment: Check [this code](https://ideone.com/uOMLK1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1fB3/1).

Comment: Write a parser for the language. See [Marpa::R2](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2) or [Parse::RecDescent](http://p3rl.org/Parse::RecDescent).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The match pattern may or may NOT follow an `if`, so your regex is a little bit limited in its scope, but I really think it's tidy and neat. Is it possible to make it applicable in more scenarioes?

Comment: Katyusza, You may remove `if\s*` and it will be a [rather generic pattern](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1fB3/2).

Comment: It is not trivial to parse Verilog : https://metacpan.org/pod/Verilog-Perl

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks buddy; I'll try your `(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|(\w+)(\s*<=[^;]*)` tomorrow ;-)

Comment: I believe you should try toolic's suggestion.

Comment: The reason why I do not use a ready parser is that, I think as a beginner I can learn a lot while hand-crafting such a parser on my own, even if it's very, very ugly parser >,<

Comment: @katyusza: If you go down that route then you should be aware that you're setting yourself an enormous task. But do take note of [choroba's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552120/how-to-do-conditional-greedy-match-in-perl/35552583?noredirect=1#comment58793563_35552120) regarding modules that you might use. You are doomed to fail if you start with simple regexes

Comment: @Borodin Got that; I will read it. Never thought there are existing stuffs to help parse any designated language!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a lot more complicated that you might imagine, and it is impossible to do properly without writing a parser for the language you are trying to process. However, you may be in luck if your sample is a consistently limited subset of the language

The best way I can see to do this is to use `split` to separate out all the subsections of the string that are in parentheses from the "top level" sections where the replacements are to be done. Then the changes can be made to the relevant parts and the split sections joined back together

Even this relies on the code having properly balanced parentheses, and an odd open or closing parenthesis that appears in, say, a string or a comment will throw the process out. The regex used in the `split` has to be recursive so that nested parentheses can be matched, and making it a *capturing* regex makes `split` returns all of the parts of the string instead of just the sections between the matches

This code will do as you ask, but beware that, as I described, it is extremely fragile

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};

my @split = split / ( \( (?> [^()] | (?1) )* \) ) /x, $data;

for ( @split ) {
    next if /[()]/;
    s/ ^ \s* \w+ \K (?= \s* <= ) /_yes/xgm;
}

print join '', @split;


__DATA__
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
if(!rst_n)begin
        d1 <= 0; //perl_comment_4
        //perl_comment_5
        d2 <= 1  //perl_comment_6
                 + 2;
        end
else if( d3 <= d4 && ( d5 <= 3 ) ) begin
        d6 <= d7 +
                 (d8 <= d9 ? 1 : 0);
        //perl_comment_7
        d10 <= d11 <=
                      d12
                        + d13
                            <= d14 ? 1 : 0;
        end
```

#### output

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
if(!rst_n)begin
        d1_yes <= 0; //perl_comment_4
        //perl_comment_5
        d2_yes <= 1  //perl_comment_6
                 + 2;
        end
else if( d3 <= d4 && ( d5 <= 3 ) ) begin
        d6_yes <= d7 +
                 (d8 <= d9 ? 1 : 0);
        //perl_comment_7
        d10_yes <= d11 <=
                      d12
                        + d13
                            <= d14 ? 1 : 0;
        end
```

Comment: @katyusza It's similar to `s/(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*\w+\K(?=\s*<=)/_yes/gm;` just more complicated and of worse performance. Further it relies on matches being preceded by linestart followed by any amount of whitespace. The recursive part was suboptimal and there is no need for `s` flag as no dot is used. [See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jP3iN3/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble: I've made the changes that I assume you meant, but they're trivial and I'm certain that they'll have no impact on the performance of the program. Unless the data is *enormous* this will be disk-bound. I really don't know what to do instead of anchroing at the start of a line: the whole thing really needs to be anchored behind at a statement boundary, which could be a semicolon of `begin` or perhaps something else, and then those must be ignored if they're inside quotes or comments. This really isn't a job for a one-off regex

Comment: @Borodin I don't see why to split/join over using `(*SKIP)(*F)` which is handy for such cases and not "magical". It discards parts that yours use as split sequence. If anchoring to start of line or consuming up to semicolon depends on the input. I would prefer semicolon variant but also yours is fine. For performance I would add `+` quantifier to `[^()]` for less alternating: [*184 steps* `\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)`](https://goo.gl/I4BkLt) vs [*50 steps* `\((?>[^()]+|(?R))*\)`](https://goo.gl/hsCxw0) or [`(\((?>[^()]*(?R)?)*\))`with *63 steps*](https://goo.gl/fbaojm)  in between. Elaborative answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble: As I said, this problem cannot be solved without regex recursion. I judge `\K` and look-aheads to be within an average Perl programmer's vocabulary, whereas far fewer have even considered backtracking or know about the star commands. If you think my criticism is wrong, then surely you are also wrong to copy it?